# Where is the Sender ID in Google Developers Console project?

Tags: sender-id

In order to send an Android push message from a server, two pieces of information are required:

- A [**Sender Id**](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key), AKA Project Id, is used in the app side. There should be no more than one id for each app.
- A Server key for contacting GCM. There might be several Server Keys for a single app so that if one is compromised it can be replaced.

The common wisdom says that the sender id should be apparent in my project page, but I can't seem to find it - any idea where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 20 minutes of agony, I found the problem - I was in the API section of the console (where the server keys are), and I needed the main console page (where the project id / sender id is).

1. Choose Google Cloud Platform:
   [image]
2. The numerical project id appears in the center of the screen.
   [image]

Comment: Thank God, they changed the GUI and I wasted 20 minutes finding it as well... Blessed be!

Answer (score 2):

I found the sender ID in another way

1. Choose the menu in the top right
   [menu Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENCVR.png)

[image]

2. Choose Project Information